# Error while executing r.js optimizer, what could be the possible issue

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs, require, bundling-and-minification, r.js

While executing require.js optimizer for bundling my backbone application, I am getting this error

> Tracing dependencies for: ./require-config TypeError: Cannot read
> property "normalize" from undefined In module tree:
> requireLib

Here is the code of my build.js

```
({
    baseUrl: './',
    mainConfigFile: './require-config.js',
    name: './require-config',
    out: './scripts.min.js',
    preserveLicenseComments: false,
    paths: {
        requireLib: './lib/require'
    },
    include: 'requireLib'
})
```